# Having PHP site point to a different path than one that is in the code

Tags: php, linux, xampp, wamp, wampserver

I am running a PHP site on Windows using Wampserver. All throughout the site there is a hardcoded line such as:

```
$settings = parse_ini_file("/usr/local/apache2/myconfigs/settings.ini", true);
```

I know this is bad practice to begin with but it is out of my control.

When the site runs is there any possible way I can trick the site to point to `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\myconfigs\settings.ini` whenever the code is looking for `/usr/local/apache2/myconfigs/settings.ini` in the parse_ini_file function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hackish but I think it's what you are looking for, so the trick here is to redefine the `parse_ini_file` function and make it ignore the invalid passed path (`"/usr/local/apache2/myconfigs/settings.ini"`) and use your correct file instead.

This seems straightforward but a bit tricky since your new function should also call the original `parse_ini_file` function somehow, that's why you need to **rename** it first then **override** it

You will need **PHP runkit extension** enabled for this, have look at [runkit_function_redefine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php) and [runkit_function_rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-rename.php) for reference.

Untested but should work, the code should be something around these lines :

```
runkit_function_rename('parse_ini_file','original_parse_ini_file');
runkit_function_redefine('parse_ini_file', function() {
    original_parse_ini_file("C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\myconfigs\settings.ini", true);
});
```

Make sure the code above is executed at the start of your application script and any `parse_ini_file` call should use your file instead of the hardcoded one.

If there is no single entry point to your application where you can put the code above, you can put it in a separate script and make PHP load before running any script via the `auto_prepend_file` setting in your `settings.ini` file, also make sure that `runkit.internal_override` is set to `On` since `parse_ini_file` is not a user defined function.

Answer (score 3):

```
$settings = parse_ini_file(APACHE_INI_PATH, true);
// $settings = parse_ini_file("/usr/local/apache2/myconfigs/settings.ini", true);
```

Comment: the goal is to keep the /usr/local path in the code since it is at the top of 100's of pages.

Comment: You could find and replace `"/usr/local/apache2/myconfigs/settings.ini"` with a PHP constant. Then you just configure it once when the environment changes.

Comment: I like the suggestion, this is the way the code should be, however it is an existing large project under source control. If I make this change it will need to be accepted company wide in over 100 files.

Comment: I also like this suggestion, but I would add you can check the server address and swap them automatically with `if($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '::1' || $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']  == '127.0.0.1')` for localhost.  Also you are already seeing the maintenance nightmare this creates, it's better to fix it permanently and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Hello please check this

```
runkit_function_rename('parse_ini_file','o_parse_ini_file');
runkit_function_redefine('parse_ini_file', function($p1,$p2)  use($someCondition) {
    if($someCondition)
        o_parse_ini_file("C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\myconfigs\settings.ini", true);
    else
        o_parse_ini_file($p1,$p2);

});
```

it can return

> Call to undefined function runkit_function_rename()

to fix this error  [please read here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/runkit.installation.php)

[or here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809451/php-runkit-function-rename-dont-work)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do a find and replace as suggested by @cddoma, I propose that you create the directory /usr/local/apache2/myconfigs/ in your windows machine, and copy the file settings.ini from C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\myconfigs\settings.ini to that directory.

Open your windows command line and enter the following

`mkdir C:\usr\local\apache2\myconfigs\`

`copy C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\myconfigs\settings.ini C:\usr\local\apache2\myconfigs\`

Comment: this will not work. C:\usr\local\apache2\myconfigs\ will not be the same as /usr/local/apache2/myconfigs/. The path is absolute, not relative so it will not know to go to the C drive.

Comment: Wamp server defaults to the installation drive. Which is C:\ in your case. I have tried it and it worked in my test case.

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to do this with a [Symbolic link on Windows](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-take-advantage-of-symbolic-links-in-window-10/)